# File Parsing and Tokenization with "\t"

Tags: python, parsing, text, tokenize

I'm currently playing with the following git repo - https://github.com/threelittlemonkeys/rnn-encoder-decoder-pytorch

I'm having issues setting up an input file.  According to the github, we need files in the following format:

source_sequence  \t  target_sequence

source_sequence  \t  target_sequence

Looking at the code, it is parsing each line and splitting it around the "\t" delmiter.  However when I run the prepare.py, I get the following error "not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)"

This seems to be occuring when it does line.split("\t").  Each of my input lines is a sequence, followed by \t, foloowed by another sequence.  Can anyone enlighten me as to what going on?

Comment: Apparently, there is some line that doesn't follow this pattern which is `[seq] \t [seq]`. Can you check your data to make sure this isn't the case?

Comment: For example, if there is an extra newline character at the end of the file, then that would be an extra line that doesn't follow [seq] \t [seq].

Comment: Yeah I made sure of that, there are no other characters after the last sequence, including a new line

Comment: Ok I figured out that line.split cannot be assigned to variables like x,y = line.split()...   So I instead did the following: x = line.split("\t")[0]
        y = line.split("\t")[1].  Now I'm getting an indexing error...